# Function callable as class method or instance method

Tags: python, function, methods, class-method, instance-methods

I have a Python class that I created previously, it looks something like this:

```
class Foo:
  @classmethod
  def bar(cls, x):
    print(x + 3)

Foo.bar(7)  # prints '10'
```

Now I would like to retrofit this interface with some state, so that the caller can create a `Foo` object, give it some properties, and then call its `bar()` method, which has access to `self` and its properties:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, y=3):
    self.y = y
  def bar(self, x):
    print(x + self.y)

Foo().bar(7)  # prints '10'
Foo(20).bar(7)  # prints '27'
```

Unfortunately, this breaks the previous interface - `Foo.bar(7)` will now give `TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`, because `Foo.bar(...)` is a simple function reference.

I can add a `@classmethod` decorator to get part way there:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, y=3):
    self.y = y
  @classmethod
  def bar(cls, x):
    self = cls()
    print(x + self.y)

Foo.bar(7)  # prints '10'
Foo().bar(7)  # prints '10'
Foo(20).bar(7)  # prints '10', but I want '27'
```

Is it possible to create a `@flexmethod` decorator that converts the other direction?  Specifically - if called as an instance method like `Foo(20).bar(...)`, then do nothing; if called as a class method like `Foo.bar(...)` then create a new `Foo` object (using no-arg constructor) and pass that as the `self` argument.

I was going to try this myself by looking at the source for `@classmethod`, but it looks like it's implemented at the C level.

Comment: The question marked as an "exact duplicate" is not the same - that one is (in my terms) how to get `Foo(20).bar(7)` and `Foo.bar(20, 7)` to behave the same, mine is about `Foo(20).bar(7)` and `Foo.bar(7)`.  The distinction is important because the whole point is to keep the existing interface `Foo.bar(7)`.

Comment: Just realized - even though the *question* isn't the same, @user2357112's solution includes a solution to my problem as well.  I'll give it a shot when I get to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods) has entire section on how `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` work, and how to implement variations on them, including this pure-Python equivalent to `classmethod`:

```
class ClassMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(obj)
        def newfunc(*args):
            return self.f(klass, *args)
        return newfunc
```

If it isn't obvious to you how that works, you probably need to read the whole HOWTO. I've got [a blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html) that tries to provide an introduction to the method-related stuff first, which may help get over the abstraction hump of the first part of the HOWTO.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to work with that and see if I can come up with something.  If I do, I'll post it as a new answer.